# Como passar matlab para python?

Tags: python

```
f0 = 20000;
a0 = 1;
alfa = 0;
T1 = f0/a0; 
sigma1 = T1*cos(deg2rad(alfa));
tau1 = T1*sin(deg2rad(alfa));
    for teta=0:1:180
          tau(teta+1) = (sigma1/2)*sin(deg2rad(2*teta));
          sigma(teta+1) = (sigma1/2)*(1+cos(deg2rad(2*teta)));
    end
plot(sigma,tau);
```

Comment: Todas as funções trigonométricas utilizadas estão presentes no Python no pacote [math](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html). Dê uma lida na documentação que entenderá facilmente como funcionam. Já para a criação do gráfico, veja o pacote [matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org).

Answer (score -1):

Para iniciar o mecanismo MATLAB® em uma sessão do Python, você deve primeiro instalar a API do mecanismo como um pacote Python. O MATLAB fornece um arquivo setup.py padrão do Python para construir e instalar o mecanismo usando o módulo distutils. Você pode usar os mesmos comandos setup.py para criar e instalar o mecanismo em sistemas Windows®, Mac ou Linux®.

Antes de instalar, verifique as configurações do Python e do MATLAB.

Seu sistema tem uma versão suportada do Python e do MATLAB R2014b ou posterior. Para verificar se o Python está instalado no sistema, execute o Python no prompt do sistema operacional.

Adicione a pasta que contém o interpretador Python ao seu caminho, se ainda não estiver lá.

Encontre o caminho para a pasta MATLAB. Inicie o MATLAB e digite matlabroot na janela de comando. Copie a rota retornada pelo matlabroot.

Para instalar a API do mecanismo, execute os seguintes comandos no prompt do sistema operacional, em que matlabroot é o caminho para a pasta MATLAB. Você pode precisar de privilégios de administrador para executar esses comandos. Como alternativa, use uma das opções não padrão descritas em Instalar a API do mecanismo MATLAB para Python em locais não padrão.

Nos sistemas Windows -

cd "matlabroot \ extern \ engines \ python"
instalação de python setup.py
Nos sistemas Mac ou Linux -

cd "matlabroot / extern / engines / python"
instalação de python setup.py

**Esta na documentação**: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/install-the-matlab-engine-for-python.html